# Cluster Trend Data

Tags: cluster-analysis

I am trying to cluster trend data similar to that created by

```
data = Table[
   RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20] + 10 offset, {offset, 1, 10, 1}] // Flatten
```

This data is highly simplified and has a fixed number of values for each cluster. In general this will not be true but the number of possible clusters will be known in advance. The noise level may also vary for each cluster and the average distance between clusters may vary.

Automatic clustering by

```
ClusteringComponents[data, 10]
ListPlot[%]
```

is nearly correct but is not stable. In general, I am looking for methods to pre-determine the `CritionFunction` and `DistanceFunction`, etc. from the data to stabilize the clustering.

I have previously seen a similar problem discussed here but I cannot locate it via search. Probably just the wrong keywords.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "nearly correct but is not stable". Have you tried `FindClusters`? e.g.

```
FindClusters[data, Method -> "DBSCAN"] // ListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried FindClusters. This is essentially the same functionality as in ClusteringComponents. Not stable means that with default settings the result is not reproducible given the variation provided by RandomReal with limits +/-1 and the offset of 10 per step/cluster.